# How to combine two option group to filter listbox, in ms access

Tags: ms-access, radio-button

I have a form with listbox, based on query.
I have two option groups on my form, and want to combine filter result, to show filtered result same time, if I toggle between options.

--Option group with Frame155 filters status of Articles

--Option group with Frame173 filters date criteria

Because form loads with no filter, I am having one of the options as "All" so user will know that this is All data, without any filter.

Frame155 (All, Approved, Pending)

Frame173 (All, 180days, 30days)

Problem:

If one of the options is selected in Frame155 (other than default option) then
If i move between options in Frame173, then option in this filter work, but the option which is already selected in Frame155 stops working and filters with default option "All"
Briefly: Filter options work perfectly fine independent of each other, but I want to combine those.

Here is my code for each Frame and has no difference on After Update or Click event.

```
Private Sub Frame155_AfterUpdate()
If Frame155 = 1 Then
    Me.SearchResults.RowSource = "SELECT * FROM Query1 ORDER BY Query1.ID DESC"
Else
    If Frame155 = 2 Then
        Me.SearchResults.RowSource = "SELECT * FROM Query1 " & _
        "WHERE  ((Query1.[Status])= 'Approved') ORDER BY Query1.ID DESC"
    Else
        If Frame155 = 3 Then
            Me.SearchResults.RowSource = "SELECT * FROM Query1 " & _
            "WHERE  ((Query1.[Status])= 'Pending') ORDER BY Query1.ID DESC"
```

And on another option group

```
Private Sub Frame173_AfterUpdate()
If Frame173 = 1 Then
    Me.SearchResults.RowSource = "SELECT * FROM Query1 ORDER BY Query1.ID DESC"
Else
    If Frame173 = 2 Then
        Me.SearchResults.RowSource = "SELECT * FROM Query1 " & _
        "WHERE  (((Query1.[Dateorder])>=Date()-180))ORDER BY Query1.ID DESC"
    Else
        If Frame173 = 3 Then
            Me.SearchResults.RowSource = "SELECT * FROM Query1 " & _
            "WHERE  (((Query1.[DateOrder])>=Date()-30))ORDER BY Query1.ID DESC"
```

Comment: Cross post https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/how-to-combine-two-option-group-to-filter-listbox.322937/

Comment: Have a Sub procedure that references both groups to build appropriate SQL. Call this Sub from each AfterUpdate event. Example of procedure referencing multiple controls to build SQL: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62code.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so for bot radio button groups, have it call ONE common routine.

And then you build up. This approach works if you have say your two options, or say even 5 more check box options for additional filers.

```
Sub MyFilter

   dim strSQL      as string
   dim strWhere    as string
   dim strOrderBy  as string

   strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Query1"
   strOrderBy = " ORDER BY Query1.ID DESC"
   strWhere = ""

   ' deal with approved/pending etc.
   if Frame155 <> 1 then
      ' add filter on first option group
      if Frame155 = 2 then strWhere = " [Status] = 'Approved'
      if Frame155 = 3 then strWhere = " [Status] = 'Pending'
   end if

   ' deal with 2nd group
   if Frame173 <> 1 then
      if strWhere <> "" then strWhere = strwhere & " AND "
      IF Frame173 = 2 then strWhere = strWhere & " ([Dateorder] >= Date()-180)"
      IF Frame173 = 3 then strWhere = strWhere & " ([Dateorder] >= Date()-30)"
   End if

   strSQL = strSQL & strWhere & strOrderBy

   me.RecordSource = strSQL
```

So, as you can see in above. The you can select either none (both all), the first one, the 2nd one, or both. It don't matter, since we build up the where based on choices. As noted, you could even say add a few more controls, like some [x] - include expired or whatever.

Now, in above I shove the above whole sql string right into the forms record source, and you could of couse use me.Filter, and me.Orderby as separate, but the general idea, the general approach is much the same.

So, for most of these difficult filter type forms, start out with a empty where clause, and then build it up for EACH section.

That way, the code above will and could for for your 2 option groups, but in theory you could have 5 or more.

By starting with the first group, and "optional" add the filter, then you can build up the final where clause, and you don't wind up with a combinations and permeations math like problem - which, recalling our high school math, just 5 sets of choices would require 120 different combination!!! (5! = 120).

So, above simple approach deals with this. Often for combo box, or check boxes, I just assume if un-selected, then that means "all", but regardless, the above concept and approach works rather well.